# Compiling old solaris programs under Linux

Tags: solaris, libraries

I've got sources for a program developed under Solaris in ANSI-C. I am told it was developed around 1996-1997. I'm currently struggling with compiling it under a current Ubuntu. I got pretty far and I think only the GUI is still missing. They used a library called guide for this it seems. Does anyone know, if this library still exists somewhere?

The relevant parts of the Makefile:

```
INCL    = -I$(GUIDEHOME)/include -I$(OPENWINHOME)/include
LOAD    = -L$(GUIDEHOME)/lib -L$(OPENWINHOME)/lib
LIB     = -lguide -lguidexv -lxview -lolgx -lX -lm
TAG     = -target sun4
```

Comment: What makes you think it was "guide"? Could it be "glide"? Are you getting link errors? If so, what are they? Are you getting header files missing? What are the missing headers?

Comment: I edited the answer to make it clearer.

Comment: never heard of guide... but have heard of guile

Comment: http://freshmeat.net/projects/xview http://freshmeat.net/projects/OWacomp Right or wrong track?

Comment: @ephemient: This was exactly what I was looking for. Thanks! I'd accept it if you'd change it to an answer instead of a comment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As msw says, it appears that your application wants to use the OpenWindows and Xview libraries that were provided in older Sun systems.

I believe they're not even around on newer Solaris installs anymore, but the free software projects [OpenWindows Augmented Compatibility Environment](http://freshmeat.net/projects/OWacomp) and [The XView Toolkit](http://freshmeat.net/projects/xview) may provide compatible-enough implementations of these libraries on newer systems.

Answer (score 4):

From your description it appears that these were written against the [SunOS Xview Code Generation Suite](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/801-6665/801-6665.pdf). I have a dim memory of this package which is probably roughly analogous to GTK or Java Swing, but predates most of their concepts and mechanism.

I expect the best that you can do is either:

1. Write a library that simulates libguide which is fraught with error or
2. Yank out the affected UI code and replace it with your own perhaps using something like [glade](http://glade.gnome.org/)

I don't envy you this task.

Comment: We used to give this application to our service staff "draw what you want it to look like", we would then rewrite the code ourselves as it code was horrid.